# SQL/Presto: Transpose a table

Tags: sql, presto

I have the following query, which counts the number of the pet, and display each type of pet in a row.

```
   with animal_table as (
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) AS total_count,
        COUNT_IF(any_match(my_array, x -> x LIKE '%dog%')) AS dog_count,
        COUNT_IF(any_match(my_array, x -> x LIKE '%cat%')) AS cat_count,
        COUNT_IF(any_match(my_array, x -> x LIKE '%pig%')) AS pig_count,
        COUNT_IF(any_match(my_array, x -> x LIKE '%duck%')) AS duck_count
    FROM my_table
    )


select 'dog' as pet, dog_count as pet_nums from animal_table
UNION ALL 
select 'cat' as pet, cat_count as pet_nums from animal_table
UNION ALL 
select 'pig' as pet, pig_count as pet_nums from animal_table
UNION ALL 
select 'duck' as pet, duck_count as pet_nums from animal_table
```

I use the `UNION ALL` to transpose each pet to a row. However, this is not scalable when the type of pets grow. I am wondering is there a better way to do this (table transpose)? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `group by` and [`unnest()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest):

```
select pet, count(*)
from my_table t cross join
     unnest(t.my_array) u(pet)
group by pet;
```

If you want to count rows only once, then use a primary key or:

```
select pet, count(distinct seqnum)
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by <some column>) as seqnum
      from my_table t
     ) t cross join
     unnest(t.my_array) u(pet)
group by pet;
```

Comment: Hi, this won't work. Because for each row in my_table, the my_array column could contains dog many times : my_array = ['I love my dog', 'my dog name is Max', 'my dog is a girl'] , but this row is still only count once. I think we need to transpose from animal table instead of unnest my_table.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff, but I think it still won't work. For the second, even though it counts each row only once, we didn't use the REGEX to extract the 'dog' from my_array = ['I love my dog', 'my dog name is Max', 'my dog is a girl'] . Each element in my_array is not a simple clean string which can be used for join directly.